# (Python) Extract value in a dict in list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, extract

**Hello**,
I do a new project with a Discord bot for a game (iRacing) to keep information during a race. I use pyirsdk and i look all source code to try to understand how it works.
However, I have a dict in a list and i'm blocked.

```
DriverInfo: 

{

    'DriverHeadPosX': -0.579,
    'DriverHeadPosY': 0.398,
    'DriverHeadPosZ': 0.571,

    'Drivers': 

    [

    {'CarIdx': 0, 'UserName': 'Enzo Foucaud', 'AbbrevName': '', 'Initials': '', 'UserID': 409133, 'TeamID': 0, 'TeamName': 'Enzo Foucaud', 'CarNumber': '64', 'CarNumberRaw': 64, 'CarPath': 'mercedesamggt3', 'CarClassID': 0, 'CarID': 72, 'CarIsPaceCar': 0, 'CarIsAI': 0, 'CarScreenName': 'Mercedes AMG GT3', 'CarScreenNameShort': 'Mercedes AMG GT3', 'CarClassShortName': None, 'CarClassRelSpeed': 0, 'CarClassLicenseLevel': 0, 'CarClassMaxFuelPct': '1.000 %', 'CarClassWeightPenalty': '0.000 kg', 'CarClassPowerAdjust': '0.000 %', 'CarClassColor': 16777215, 'IRating': 1, 'LicLevel': 1, 'LicSubLevel': 1, 'LicString': 'R 0.01', 'LicColor': '0xundefined', 'IsSpectator': 0, 'CarDesignStr': '1,dff000,1a4b9b,ffffff', 'HelmetDesignStr': '1,dff000,1a4b9b,ffffff', 'SuitDesignStr': '1,dff000,1a4b9b,ffffff', 'CarNumberDesignStr': '0,0,FFFFFF,777777,000000', 'CarSponsor_1': 0, 'CarSponsor_2': 0, 'CurDriverIncidentCount': 0, 'TeamIncidentCount': 0}

    ]

}
```

I do this to know if 'UserName' exist or not

```
DriversInfo_list = ir['DriverInfo']
print('DriverInfo:', DriversInfo_list)
    for i in DriversInfo_list:
        if i == 'Drivers':
            print("Drivers Exists")
            SoloDriver = DriversInfo_list['Drivers']
            print(SoloDriver)
            if [d['UserName'] for d in SoloDriver if 'UserName' in d]:
                print('Username Exists')
```

Console :

```
DriverInfo: {...}
Drivers Exists
[{'CarIdx': 0, ...}]
Username Exists
```

Now, i want to extract many info of 'Drivers' (dict) in DriverInfo who is a list.
For example i want the value of UserName but i don't know how i can do this. I search during all the day .. ^^ i do many lesson to try this ^^

Thank's for your answer

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I want Enzo Foucaud for UserName or Mercedes AMG GT3 for CarScreenName
Edit : or another value in Drivers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume each driver dict in the `Drivers` list has exactly the same keys. Otherwise will throw KeyError. To avoid this error check if the key exists in lambda.

```
drivers = ir['DriverInfo']['Drivers']
result = list(map((lambda x: x['UserName']), drivers))
```

Comment: Thank you ! it's what i want ! and i can add multiple lambda ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by multiple lambda. The `map` function is mapping each element in `drivers` list and call the lambda function. The lambda function returns `UserName` of the driver.

Answer (score 1):

It depends if all DriversInfo items contain only a list of one dictionary in the driver key. But you can do like:

```
DriversInfo_list = ir['DriverInfo']
for soloDriverInfo in DriversInfo_list['Drivers']:
    #Iterate in list of driver key
    print(f"username: {soloDriverInfo['UserName']}, car: {soloDriverInfo['CarScreenName']}")
```

Comment: Yes only one dict in DriversInfo (look on top) and your code have a problem and don't know why ? SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Comment: I forgot a" = print(f"username: {soloDriverInfo['UserName']}, car: {soloDriverInfo['CarScreenName']}")